# Has quantum tunnelling of an atom ever been empirically confirmed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-tunneling

The phenomenon first drew attention in the case of alpha decay, in which alpha particles escape from certain radioactive atomic nuclei.

But has scientists ever observed quantum tunnelling of an atom? Of a molecule?

Of course, the probability of quantum tunnelling depends on the degree of freedom. However, the question here is valid and clearly stated.

What is the biggest object that scientists has observed to quantum tunnel?

Comment: [Here](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-020-2490-7) ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13523)) is one such instance, where authors reported measuring the time the tunneling atoms spends inside the barrier.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, routinely.

One setting where this is particularly clear is in optical lattices, where atoms or molecules can be trapped in the "egg-carton" potential formed by the interference between two or more laser beams. There is typically a high degree of control over the strength and shape of the potential, and it is very common to arrange it so that atoms can tunnel between adjacent sites with reasonable probability. This setting is one of the basic ingredients for the design of quantum simulators on this platform.

Comment: What is the biggest object that scientists has observed to quantum tunnel?

Comment: @Pavel Borisov I'm not sure if they quantum tunneled, but Bucky Balls are relatively big and obey quantum effects.

Comment: Buckyballs show interference pattern - experimentally proven. But interference is a different story.